# Calc is not working on iOS 11.2.1 safari when using percentage and pixels

Tags: ios, css, safari, mobile-safari, ios11.2

I have something as simple as a class

```
.left {
  left: calc(50% - 200px);
}
```

but elements with this class don't move left at all. 
If I change it to only percentage it works:

```
.left {
  left: calc(50%);
}
```

and it is not the minus or plus cause adding and removing percentages as well as adding and removing pixels works fine:

```
.left {
  left: calc(50% - 20%);
}

.left{
  left: calc(300px - 200px);
}
```

This is only happening after the latest iOS update, so 11.2.1 . I suppose this is a bug but I would like to solve it in case apple takes forever to solve it. 
I'm not quite sure if I should solve it with js or have something as simple as a fallback with only percentages and no calc.

Anybody have any good ideas how to solve this?

Here is a fiddler in case you want to test it out yourself:

https://jsfiddle.net/zk5wt3de/1/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: percentage in calc doesn't seem to be working.
By setting width and max-width i was able to get the correct size.

```
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 62px);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with webkit prefix, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```
-webkit-calc(50% - 200px);
-moz-calc(50% - 200px);
 calc(50% - 200px);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant this will be in the future, but it seems as though currently there is a bug in ios where calc doesn't work at all, even with the correct prefixes.

Comment: @Chaosxmk I am experiencing the same issue - but cannot find any reference/ticket on Apple's site, do you know more details? Thanks